# How to 'delete between and including quotes, but not leading/trailing whitespace'?

Tags: vim

```
'bla bla bla', 'bla bla bla'
---------------^------------ (cursor position)
```

To delete the second 'bla bla bla' I use

```
da'
```

but this also deletes the leading space. Is there a way to not include the leading space in the deletion?

(I'm trying to create a macro to replace quoted strings with a function call, ie replace eg

```
'bla bla bla', 'woot'
```

with

```
yada('bla_bla_bla'), yada('woot') )
```

Comment: Related: [Is there a motion similar to a" that never includes leading whitespace?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3789/205) (on [vi.se])

Answer (score 2):

in macro you can also use command, like this:

```
s/'.\{-}'/yada(&)/g
```

This will only apply on `'...'`, the rest (space, comma etc) won't be touched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vi'i'<operator>` to operate on the quotes and their content. This would make your macro look something like that:

```
vi'i'cyada(<C-r>")
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out an alternative "adi'xhxiyada("apa") :-). Yours is slightly shorter.